# Python3 remote interpreter (Linux -> Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Pycharm 2019.1 (Linux host) can't successfully setup a remote interpreter (Windows host).

Path is in system environment variables.

SSH communication link works fine, port 22 is open for Linux host IP.

PyCharm successfully setups a remote interpreter only for Windows host - Linux guest.

```
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What it can be? I don't understand what `'env'` means, because I can create virtual environments and execute code in Windows without issues.

Comment: `env` is a command frequently used in the Linux world to set environment variables for the program you want to execute. But of course this program does not exists in the windows world, and since SSH is new in the Windows world, most tools still expect SSH connections as Linux. Since the command line of `env` is simple, it shouldn't be too hard to create your own replacement in C or c++

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment PyCharm doesn't natively support SSH on Windows https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20952 The error is indeed triggered by PyCharm trying to work with Windows as Linux.